sentence that include 'and' need to analysis
First question
A definition of pedagogy in The New Oxford English-Chinese Dictionary:

the method and practice of teaching, especially as an academic subject or theoretical concept

for the method and practice of teaching, how should I analyze the definition structure?
Use parentheses to represent it as a whole.
So is it like
(the method and practice) of teaching
or
(the method) and (practice of teaching)?
Second question
In sentence Second:

We hope that this book will provide you with an intuitive understanding of
the theoretical and practical aspects of electronics in a way that fuels your creativity.

Use parentheses to represent it as a whole.
So is it like
(an intuitive understanding of the theoretical) and (practical aspects of electronics)
or
an intuitive understanding of (the theoretical and practical aspects of electronics)
or else other?
Are there any rules for this type of "and" sentence?  Or is there any material that explains this?
Thank you.

(1) Both the method of teaching and the practice of teaching.  (2) Both the theoretical aspects and the practical aspects.

"the method and practice of teaching, especially as an academic subject or theoretical concept" isn't a sentence.

The construction X and Y of Z can be ambiguous and can mean (X and Y) of Z, or X and (Y of Z).  This usually can be solved by context.
We add a few words to the OP’s
first example to make it a sentence:

[Let's consider] the method and practice of teaching, especially as an academic subject or theoretical concept.

From context, the method and practice of teaching has to mean

(the method and practice) of teaching

The sentence can be expanded to

Let's consider (the method of teaching) and (the practice of teaching), especially as an academic subject or theoretical concept.

Omitting the of teaching after method and the second noun phrase would make the sentence unclear as the method can't stand alone:

*Let's consider the method, especially as an academic subject or theoretical concept.

With some other nouns for X and Y, the analysis could be different. In a discussion about a certain topic,

Let's consider the practical usefulness and feasibility of teaching, especially as an academic subject or theoretical concept.

Here practical usefulness can stand alone.
So there're no fixed rules in analysing a construction
X and Y of Z.
The OP's second example
means this, as expanded:

We hope that this book will provide you with an intuitive understanding of the theoretical aspects of electronics
and practical aspects of electronics in a way that fuels your creativity.

Omitting aspects of electronics after theoretical and the second noun phrase
would make the sentence unclear as theoretical can't stand alone:

*... understanding of the theoretical in a way that fuels your creativity.


In both cases, your second example is the correct way to partition the sentence meaning with parentheses.

I'm sorry, my native language isn't English, and I didn't understand what you were saying.

You gave two examples. For each example, the second proposed solution is the correct way to add parenthesis.

Thank you for your explain. Before asking this question, I didn't know which method of analyzing the structure was correct.

Miss Understands doesn't 'In both cases, your second example is the correct way to partition the sentence meaning with parentheses' mean '(the method) and (practice of teaching)' is correct?
In that case the first example was correct: '(the method and practice) of teaching…'
Can you say how first and second got mixed up there?

FYI, there is no 'correct way to add parenthesis…' the concept is too alien.
That might be fine somewhere such as English Language Usage but here in ELL, how could it be other than confusing?
The example might be an acceptable way to partition a sentence using parentheses, but where is that a standard tool with a single 'correct' application?
In any case, did you want to 'partition the sentence' or to use  parentheses to help analyse of hi-light the meaning.
In ELU that might be pedantic. In ELL, how could 'partition the sentence meaning' be anything but confusing?
